# Is there a name for this type of blue-sy/90s pop transition on Piano

Tags: piano, keyboard, digital-piano, blues, pop-music

I absolutely love the [blue-sy transition in this song](https://clyp.it/5gcmp32v) (seconds 4-5). It's kind of like overshooting a note and coming back to it with some blues notes mixed in (bear with me, my technical knowledge here is ZERO). I can't really figure out what's going on, though. I mean, I can play the same melody/basic notes that the keyboardist is playing (one key at a time), and it doesn't sound the same. They seem to be doing multiple notes at a time for each step along the transition, or something.

Anyways, I've heard this kind of transition in a lot of electric piano type music from the 90s especially, and I love it. I'd love to learn it; to figure out what's going on. But I don't even know what to search for.

Is there a name for this type of transition? Also, what *is* going on in it? Any ideas where I can watch/read more about this type of transition?

Answer (score 2):

It is the blue notes! They are usually thought of as 1, b3, 4, b5, 5, b7.Here in Dm, moving to G maj., the flourish is A, Ab, G, F, D, I think

Comment: Thanks Tim! I can reproduce the "tune" so to speak, but if all I do is play the single notes A then Ab, then G, F, D...it doesn't sound the same. I mean: they're not just playing single notes at a time, they're playing multiple notes at a time. I'm wondering as a whole what needs to be put together to re-create that--not just the main melody line. :-) Because the "melody" of it is great, and bluesy, but really the whole package is what gives it such a great feel.